# "Bottomless" Collection View (Load more images)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm using the SDWebImage library to download and cache images for use in a UICollectionView grid view. Everything works great with the initial load of 24 images (3 across, 8 down) but I'd like to add another 24 images when the user hits the bottom of the screen. Does anyone know how I trigger this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView so you can detect the when you have reached the current "bottom" the same way by implementing UIScrollViewDelegate methods. Check this post out on how to do it:

[UIScrollView, reaching the bottom of the scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217900/uiscrollview-reaching-the-bottom-of-the-scroll-view)