# UIAlertView - accessing subviews, scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I am implementing something like Eula in my iPhone app. I need to enable the confirm button only when user reads whole Eula (scrolls along whole long text).

I am using UIAlertView, with long inside text. Thanks to this, the text field inside alert view have a scroll bar on its right side.

I need to access the delegate of this scroll, because I need to enable OK button only if user scrolls down with scrollable text.

Comment: You could check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217900/uiscrollview-reaching-the-bottom-of-the-scroll-view since UITextView respond to `contentOffset`/`contentSize`

Comment: the long test is inside the message of UIAlertView or is a UITextView on UIAlertView?

Comment: The long text is directly inside the UIAlertView message. Any special UITextView was NOT added to the UIAlertView.

Comment: Don't you want to use a simple UIScrollView where the button becomes visibale at the end? And then you can add a third button with text `TL;DR` which also accepts the eula.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to release this app on the AppStore, you can't do it using the builtin UIAlertView.
UIAlertView doesn't have any method, and it's delegate protocol doesn't give you this kind of information.

Probably you can achieve this iterating through the subviews of the UIAlertView instance, but doing this will guarantee your app the rejection :-)

the only thing you can do is to create your own "MYAlertView" component

Comment: Yes, probably this will be the best choice. I will try to follow the design of standard dialog.