# Detect direction of scrolling UICollectionView, load data from REST

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Assuming standard configuration (up/down), I'd like to detect when a user is scrolling their `UIColletionView` up or down (which is subclass of `UIScrollView` and conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`). I don't see any information straight out of the delegate to detect this, although I may be over looking something.

If I know which direction the user is scrolling, then I can use these `UICollectionViewDatasource` methods to determine if I should load more data from the REST server, or purge information that I already have to manage fixed memory space.

// If scrolling down, section is appearing

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

// If scrolling down, last cell in section is disappearing

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

// If scrolling up, last cell in section is appearing

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

// If scrolling up, section is disappearing

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217900/uiscrollview-reaching-the-bottom-of-the-scroll-view To know you have reached the bottom.

Comment: I already know how to detect if I've reached the bottom. Thx.

Comment: If you want to know if is going to up (or down): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706152/iphone-knowing-if-a-uiscrollview-reached-the-top-or-bottom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check UIScrollView's (which UICollectionView inherits from) panGestureRecognizer property and do something like this:

```
CGPoint scrollVelocity = [collectionView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:collectionView.superview];
if (scrollVelocity.y > 0.0f) {
    NSLog(@"going down");
} else if (scrollVelocity.y < 0.0f) {
    NSLog(@"going up");
}
```

**Swift 3.1**:

```
let scrollVelocity = collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.velocityInView(collectionView.superview)
if (scrollVelocity.y > 0.0) {
    print("going down")
} else if (scrollVelocity.y < 0.0) {
    print("going up")
}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. In case edits dont' make it, just realize that velocityInView returns a CGPoint struct, not a float. You need to check the y value if your collection view is a vertical scoller.

Comment: @HCHogan I tried it but scrollView is null. What should be yourView? the UiCollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this:

```
CGPoint translation = [collectionView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:collectionView.superview];
        if (translation.y > 0) {
            NSLog(@"DOWN");
        } else {

            NSLog(@"UP");
        }
```

More accurate